# How to return a list of GroupBy values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I'm trying to return the list of values in a GroupBy or even just the unique Id of those in the GroupBy but don't quite understand how to.

This is what I have so far

```
var adjustmentsToDelete = adjustments.GroupBy(x => new {x.QueryId, x.FeeTypeId})
                         .Where(group => group.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

I have a table of Adjustments that are made to Orders when a Customer raises a Query.  So for this I want to group the adjustments by QueryId and FeeTypeId and return all the grouped records or at least the unique Id (adjustmentId) of each of the grouped records.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks :)

Comment: So what is the problem? What is not working as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below and select fields which you want.

```
var adjustmentsToDelete = adjustments.GroupBy(x => new {x.QueryId, x.FeeTypeId})
                                  .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                                  .Select(x => new {x.Key.QueryId, x.Key.FeeTypeId}).ToList();
```

You can iterate above result as below for the multiple fileds.

```
foreach(var item in adjustmentsToDelete)
{
    foreach(var item in adjustmentsToDelete.QueryId)
    {
        //Use QueryId
    }

    foreach(var item in adjustmentsToDelete.FeeTypeId)
    {
        //Use FeeTypeId 
    }
}
```

If you want to select any single field than try this.

```
var adjustmentsToDelete = adjustments.GroupBy(x => new {x.QueryId, x.FeeTypeId})
                                  .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                                  .Select(x => new {x.Key.QueryId}).ToList();
```

Than use your result as follow for single field.

```
foreach(var item in adjustmentsToDelete)
{
    //use this item object as per it's properties.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting back a enumerable of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`.

You can enumerate over the results like this:

```
foreach ( var group in adjustmantsToDelete )
{
    //access group key
    Debug.WriteLine(group.Key.QueryId);
    Debug.WriteLine(group.Key.FeeTypeId);

    //enumerate items in the group
    foreach ( item in group ) 
    {
         //item's type is the same as the 
         //source collection item type
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var adjustmentsToDelete = adjustments.GroupBy(x => new {x.QueryId, x.FeeTypeId})
                                  .Where(group => group.Count() > 1);
```

There is no problem your LINQ. You can set condition and grouping but not get result.

If you think of this as a sql statement, you have not written the `select` part

Add `select` statment on `LINQ`

```
   .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
   .Select(x => new {x.Key.QueryId, x.Key.FeeTypeId}).ToList();
```